# how to transform a function from mysql into mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

hello i would like to transform a mysql-function into a mysqli version. this function is for checking if an user exists or not. so i'm new to functions and even to mysqli. thats why i'm having problems while transforming it.

the mysql-version is:

```
function a($uname){
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`a`) FROM `table_1` WHERE `a`='$uname'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

the mysqli-version i thought would be:

```
function a($uname){
        return (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT (`a`) FROM `table_1` WHERE `a`='$uname'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
    }
```

i know that there is no mysql_result anymore. i decided to use mysqli_num_rows. but this function does not work and i have no clue why. error_reporting is enabled but when calling the page, i will get a blank page with no error messages?!

so if there is someone who could help me out i really would appreciate.

thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Freely from the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php): 
`mysqli->query` returns either a mysqli_result object for queries, which actually return some results, 'false' for failed queries and 'true' for all other queries (if successful).

You will not know anything about the result of your query, unless you check the result more thoroughly.

Try something like this: (This assumes that the connection has been successfully established, and that $uname has been properly escaped.)

```
function a($uname) {
    $found = false;
    $result = mysqli->query("SELECT `a` FROM `table_1` WHERE `a`='$uname'");
    if($result) {
        //We used a 'SELECT' query and the query was successful. That means, we now have a mysqli_result object.
        $found = ($result->num_rows == 1);   //Determines, if something was actually found or not.
        $result->close(); //Frees some ressources. Not necessary, but doesn't hurt either.
    } else { //The query failed, as such we have nothing to evaluate.
         die("Queryerror: ".mysqli->error);
    }
    return $found;
}
```

I changed the query parameter from 'COUNT' to 'a', because otherwise 'num_rows' will ALWAYS return 1, even if the actual count is '0'. This way, it returns the number of matched rows, essentially return '0' for 'no match' or '1' for 'match'.

Comment: I seriously hate it, when someone votes my answers down, but doesn't even have the courtesy to leave any reason as to WHY they downvoted it. I mean, they don't do it for the mere fun of it, do they?

Answer (score 0):

You need a helper function to put all dirty mysqli internals behind the scenes.
Like [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql). It can mimic mysql_result as well:

```
function a($uname){
    global $db; // with mysqi you have to connect once and then use this connection
    return (bool)$db->getOne("SELECT COUNT (1) FROM table_1 WHERE a=?s"), $uname);
}
```

and can solve dozens of similar issues.